# how to display .txt file values in textbox or datagrid using c#

Tags: c#, textbox, wpfdatagrid

I am developing one application. I need to display the .txt file values in text box.
so can any one tell me the codes to display the .txt file values in text box or data grid using c#?

Comment: stack overflow is not a code generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string fileTxt = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\.....");
textbox.Text = fileTxt;
```